# Как изменить язык

Tags: c#, вывод, локализация

Изучаю C# по книге Марка Прайса, `C#9 и .NET 5`.

Есть класс `Person`:

```cs
using static System.Console;

namespace Packt.Shared {
    public class Person
    {
        public string? Name;
        public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Когда вывожу информацию о человеке:

```cs
var bob = new Person();
bob.Name = "Bob Smith";
bob.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1965, 12, 22);

WriteLine(
    format: "{0} was born on {1:dddd, d MMMM yyyy}",
    arg0: bob.Name,
    arg1: bob.DateOfBirth
);
```

выводится немного неприятный вывод:

```
Bob Smith was born on среда, 22 декабря 1965
```

Мой вопрос состоит в том, как мне изменить язык вывода. Для примера: вывод должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
Bob Smith was born on Wensday, 22 December 1965
```

Надеюсь всё понятно, если нет, пишите в комментариях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно изменить культуру по умолчанию на Английский. Можно использовать [инвариантную](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture#remarks), так как она тоже "Английский".

Подключите неймспейс

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Добавьте в начало кода

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: Добавил, но не работает. Не может найти `CultureInfo` .

Comment: @NickolayChistov `using System.Globalization;`